# React select. Change all selects i table

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with react select. I map row in table and i add Select to maped row. When i am changing select option in one row other rows change too. How can i make to change only one select.
This is my select:

```
<tbody>
      {deviceData.map((device, index) => (
        <tr
          key={index}
          className={mergeClasses(
            'flex justify-between w-full px-4 md:text-sm text-dark py-4 w-full border-b',
            device.extensionInpossible ? 'bg-grey-150' : '',
          )}
        >
          <td className="w-tableCellWith">{device.serialNumber}</td>
          <td className="w-tableCellWith">{device.businessNumber}</td>
          <td className="w-tableCellWith">{device.pinNumber}</td>
          <td className="w-tableCellWith">
            {new Date(device.expiryDate).toLocaleDateString()}
          </td>
          <td className="w-tableCellWith">
            <Select
              className="w-[135px] text-sm"
              components={{ IndicatorSeparator: () => null }}
              defaultValue={prolongValues[0]}
              isDisabled={device.extensionInpossible}
              name="select"
              onChange={(value) => handleOnChange(value)}
              options={prolongValues}
              placeholder={t('common:none')}
              value={selectedOption}
            />
          </td>
          <td className="w-tableCellWith">
            <div>
              <p>{(device.price * selectedOption.value).toFixed(2)}</p>
              <p className="text-grey">{`${(device.price * selectedOption.value * vat).toFixed(
                2,
              )} ${t('common:withVat')}`}</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
```

handle on change and state:

```
const [selectedOption, setOption] = useState(prolongValues[0]);
  const handleOnChange = (value: any) => {
    setOption(value);
    console.log(value);
  };
```

and my options:

```
prolongValues = [
      { value: 0, label: 'Brak' },
      { value: 1, label: '1 rok' },
      { value: 2, label: '2 lata' },
    ],
```

Comment: If you have a Select in multiple rows, each one needs to be able to identity *which* row is changing and only update that particular state (i.e. you need multiple option data to feed the Select as well as knowing which option is being updated for the `handleOnChange`

Comment: How can i identity witch row is changing?

Comment: You have cut out all context of where this `Select` exists, but there *must* be a key or other identifier from the surrounding context for the *other data* in the row along with *this row's* "option".

Comment: I add to question my <tbody>. I have index for a table row

Comment: `index` would be the obvious key into your data for what element is changing. Everything within your Select needs to key off the `device` or `index` to know what current value and which to update when you change it.